# Python - Replace None with empty string in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I want to replace None with empty string in Nested Dictionary.

```
test={
  "order":1234,
  "status":"delivered",
   "items":[
        {
          "name":"sample1",
          "code":"ASU123",
          "unit":None
      } ],
   "product":{"name":None,"code":None}
  }
```

I want to replace None with an empty string and store conversion of the dictionary into another variable like test1.

The following code is not allowing me to store it in another variable.

```
def replace_none(test_dict): 
  
    # checking for dictionary and replacing if None 
    if isinstance(test_dict, dict): 
        
        for key in test_dict: 
            if test_dict[key] is None: 
                test_dict[key] = '' 
            else: 
                replace_none(test_dict[key]) 
  
    # checking for list, and testing for each value 
    elif isinstance(test_dict, list): 
        for val in test_dict: 
            replace_none(val)
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine with your example. `replace_none(test)` modifies `test` in-place so that all the `None`s are empty strings. To save it to another variable, create a [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), and modify the copy.

Comment: `The following code is not allowing me to store it in another variable.` - does this mean you want your function to return an updated dict/list, rather than (as it does now) return nothing while updating the old one in place?

Comment: @Pranav : Thanks for your reply and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @[Pranav Hosangadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi) mentioned, you can deep-copy `test` at first and then perform your function on the copied dict:

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(test)
replace_none(b)
print(test)
print(b)
```

output:

```
{'order': 1234, 'status': 'delivered', 'items': [{'name': 'sample1', 'code': 'ASU123', 'unit': None}], 'product': {'name': None, 'code': None}}
{'order': 1234, 'status': 'delivered', 'items': [{'name': 'sample1', 'code': 'ASU123', 'unit': ''}], 'product': {'name': '', 'code': ''}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have voted for the answer and looking the same.